# Redirect to HTTPS fails to work on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, phpmyadmin

I am using a Synology NAS.  I am trying to redirect to https for phpMyAdmin.  The following works for all except for phpMyAdmin.

What I have used:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80 _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/services/web"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

What I notice is if I enter the address as "http://example.com/phpMyAdmin" it will redirect to "https://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin" but if I enter "http://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin" no redirect happens. If I try "http://www.example.com" or another folder such as, "http://www.example.com/test" it will redirect to https. It will not redirect when pointed to phpMyAdmin.

Please give me ideas on what I can do to trouble shoot this.

Comment: can you test this `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: No, same results.

Comment: open phpmyadmin file `config.inc.php` and add following line in bottom `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;`.

Comment: That command has been removed from phpMyAdmin after an update about a year ago.  It does not work any more.  I think they took it out for security purposes.  It is safer to do the redirect from the config.  Which was working. But it is not working in this case now.  Every thing else redirects except phpMyAdmin.

Comment: That is everything else redirects except "http : // www . example.com/phpMyAdmin"

Answer (score 0):

The answer, due to this being a Synology NAS, is to do the HTTPS redirect in Nginx.  I am not sure why given the fact that I have selected Apache 2.2 for my backend.  Nevertheless, Nginx it is.  I followed instructions found here:

https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=115182